# Can I really use the PayPal Standard Integration without the server.js code?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, quickbase

I have been trying to use the PayPal Standard Integration code generated by the integration builder on PayPal's developer site.  I want to utilize it in a QuickBase code page.  From the integration builder, I see the app.js code, the check out HTML which references the app.js, and the server.js code, which I don't know what to do with.  Tech support told me that I did not need the server.js code.  They haven't been much help beyond that.  I figured out how to call the app.js in the check out HTML but, I don't know how to update the app.js to get everything to work.  The buttons render but clicking on each one, at first was giving me a "SyntaxError: unexpected token '<'" error.  I got past that and am now getting "TypeError: Failed to Fetch".

Tech support said the unexpected token error I was getting was because it couldn't find the URL for the api/orders.  Unfortunately, that was all they left me with.  Looking at the line that reads **const response = await fetch("/api/orders", {**, I figured an URL pointing to the /api/orders needed to be in the beginning of the string. Nothing I have tried works but it does resolve the unexpected token error I was intially getting.

Ultimately, I want to be able to provide a dropdown list of items to choose from, allow people to provide a quantity for their selection(s), and give some comments (if any) for their selection(s).  The Add to cart functionality would be great but, I'll take what I can get at this point.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide a link to the PayPal documentation you are you using. You also might want to check your console to see if you are getting any CORS issues, Quickbase Code Pages don't allow cross-origin resource sharing and the code may be try to reach out to code hosted by PayPal. I've implemented some PayPal integrations with QB Codes in the past (been a couple years) so I believe what you are after is feasible. I also don't think you need the server.js file (that is typically what you what use to implement server from server-side). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Here is the integration builder site. https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/

Answer (score 0):

You've been misinformed, a [standard integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) *does* require a server-side backend of some type to create and capture/execute an order via API. The provided `server.js` is an example implementation (in node.js), but any suitable backend/environment can be used for that.

For an alternative that does *not* require a backend, you can try https://www.paypal.com/buttons/ and making sure you are "Logged In". Depending on your account's country and how soon it's been rolled out, you may see this new feature:

[image]

Buttons generated there do not require a backend.

If you need more advanced functionality like a cart, there are many "off the shelf" and open source solutions available, and practically all of them have a payment module that integrates with PayPal. PayPal itself has a [partner solution directory](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/solution-providers), or you can just search the web or check what your web hosting provider makes readily available for installation/activation.

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with the buttons. That is legacy code. PayPal advised that I need to upgrade, which is why I am on this path. Since I can still currently use those buttons, I okay for now but just want to get ahead of things. If possible.

Comment: No, the above does not discuss legacy buttons.

Comment: That PayPal.com/buttons is not legacy?

Comment: Some are. Not what the above answer discusses.

Comment: Oh. That particular Pay Link or Button that you shared a screen shot of is not? Gonna check that out more.

Comment: Right. Availability could be limited at the moment (phased roll-out) but I expect it'll be global in weeks or so

Comment: I see. Unless Erich comes up with something, it sounds like I will have to change platforms to get the functionality I want. I need the ability to pass comments from the buyer with the purchase. I can work around the lack of cart functionality.